# How to build a compact docker image with Tensorflow 1, CUDA 11, OpenCV and Pytorch on board

Tags: docker, tensorflow, nvidia

I'm building a docker image with Tensorflow 1, Pytorch, OpenCV and JupyterLab on board which would work on NVidia A100 GPU. As far as I can see CUDA 11 is required for A100 to work.

I have found a proper base image in NVidia NGC Catalog - https://catalog.ngc.nvidia.com/orgs/nvidia/containers/tensorflow/tags

It already features JupyterLab, and there are options that include Tensorflow 1 and Cuda 11. I need to add OpenCV and Pytorch.

The problem is that i.e. the initial nvcr.io/nvidia/tensorflow:22.04-tf1-py3 image is already 14.39Gb which is too much (2-3Gb would be good). Is there a way to compact this image, or maybe some other base images would work better for me?

Answer (score 1):

One potential way is using `nvidia/cuda` as base image. The size of `nvidia/cuda:11.2.0-cudnn8-devel-ubuntu20.04` is 6.93G; however, adding `TensorFlow` and `PyTorch` will make it at least 10G even if you do everything parsimoniously. Here is my [attempt](https://github.com/xuan-wei/nvidia-pytorch-tensorflow-conda-jupyter-ssh) with `nvidia-pytorch-tensorflow-conda-jupyter-ssh`. The size is 14.6G. You can try to simplify it by removing unnecessary parts.

Answer (score -1):

I use multi-stage builds with nvcr.io/nvidia/cuda:11.8.0-cudnn8-runtime-ubi8, registry.access.redhat.com/ubi9:latest, python:3.11.4, and registry.access.redhat.com/ubi9/ubi-micro:latest. Create base rootfs with ubi9:latest adding glibc minimal, libstdc++, zlib, xz-libs, and bzip2-libs then copy that into the ubi9:micro, then copy /usr/local/lib, /usr/local/bin, and /usr/local/include/python3.11 from python:3.11.4 into micro, and finally copy /usr/local/cuda from cuda:11.8.0-cudnn8-runtime-ubi8 into final micro. My final Python3.11.4-cuda11.8.0 ubi9-micro image is 1.2GB, then I pip install the torch and torchvision gpu wheels for cuda 11.8 along with mlflow-skinny, numpy, and pandas. That final pytorch-cuda image is 3.4GB. I have also built a Cuda micromamba image within ubi9-micro and its roughly the same size. I use these images as bases for running training jobs in openshift using argo workflow.

Multi-stage builds will always yield the smallest final container size.